# Select from MYSQL where the first four characters are

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database, in one of the fields occasionally I get an entry which starts off as mail.domainname.com

Is it possible using mysql and php to select only the rows from the field hostname where the first 4 characters = 'mail'?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One way to do it is to use [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE hostname LIKE 'mail%'
```

Another is to use [`SUBSTR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE SUBSTR(hostname, 1, 4) ='mail'
```

Comment: SUBSTRING() is 1 index based rather than 0: `SUBSTRING(hostname, 1, 4)=='mail'`

Comment: Nice catch. Too much PHP on my end. :)

Comment: I know the feeling! Very confusing when you miss it out!

Answer (score 3):

Case sensitive:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE hostname LIKE BINARY 'mail%'
```

Case insensitive:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE hostname LIKE 'mail%'
```

Comment: Good call on the case sensitivity

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

`SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE SUBSTR(field_name, 1, 4) = 'mail'`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use SQL LIKE operator: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: Don't recommend w3schools.com as a reference. It's full of errors, see http://w3fools.com

Comment: i have seen w3fools and a lot of their arguments are arguments imho.. and in all cases w3schools is a reasonable website - despite not being perfect.. nothing is perfect.. one should not generalize.. the SQL LIKE page I referred to looks fine to me. Any errors you notice on the link?

Comment: I miss a reference to `_` and the need to escape `%` and `_` in user input.